# How to respond to second argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

I'm working on a program that would take 2 arguments in an input so for example:

```
console xbox
```

"console" was the first argument, "xbox" was the second one

i tried to do something like:

```
if game == "console" + variable:
```

...
...

As "variable" would be where the second argument goes to, but the variable shouldn't have any lists with predefined strings or anything like that, i want the second argument to be completely random and then would like for the program to be able to interact with it. How would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the docuemntation for [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sys.html#sys.argv).
Basically if you call your script as `python script.py console xbox` you would get a behaviour like:

```py
import sys

"script.py" == sys.argv[0] # True
"console" == sys.argv[1]   # True
"xbox" == sys.argv[2]      # True
"console xbox" == sys.argv # False
```